# List of SYNTAX for logstash's grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

The syntax for a grok pattern is %{SYNTAX:SEMANTIC}. How do i generate a list of all available SYNTAX keywords ? I know  that I can use the grok debugger to discover patterns from text. But is there a list which i can scan through?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They are in GIT and included somewhere in the distribution.  But it's probably just easiest to view it online:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/v1.4.0/patterns/grok-patterns

Comment: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns

Answer (score 6):

The grok patterns files are now in the [logstash-patterns-core](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core) repository.
Assuming you have a clone of it in the `logstash-patterns-core` directory on your filesystem, you can issue a command like this one to list all SYNTAX keywords:

```
$ find ./logstash-patterns-core/patterns -type f -exec awk '{print $1}' {} \; | grep "^[^#\ ]" | sort
```

As of commit [6655856](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/commit/6655856ed58aaba448b535f4cc22a6ea24b074d0), the output of the command (aka the list of SYNTAX keywords) looks like this (remember though that this list is not static):

```
BACULA_CAPACITY
BACULA_DEVICE
BACULA_DEVICEPATH
BACULA_HOST
BACULA_JOB
BACULA_LOG_ALL_RECORDS_PRUNED
BACULA_LOG_BEGIN_PRUNE_FILES
BACULA_LOG_BEGIN_PRUNE_JOBS
BACULA_LOG_CANCELLING
BACULA_LOG_CLIENT_RBJ
BACULA_LOG_DIFF_FS
BACULA_LOG_DUPLICATE
BACULA_LOG_ENDPRUNE
BACULA_LOG_END_VOLUME
BACULA_LOG_FATAL_CONN
BACULA_LOG_JOB
BACULA_LOG_JOBEND
BACULA_LOGLINE
BACULA_LOG_MARKCANCEL
BACULA_LOG_MAX_CAPACITY
BACULA_LOG_MAXSTART
BACULA_LOG_NEW_LABEL
BACULA_LOG_NEW_MOUNT
BACULA_LOG_NEW_VOLUME
BACULA_LOG_NO_AUTH
BACULA_LOG_NO_CONNECT
BACULA_LOG_NOJOBS
BACULA_LOG_NOJOBSTAT
BACULA_LOG_NOOPEN
BACULA_LOG_NOOPENDIR
BACULA_LOG_NOPRIOR
BACULA_LOG_NOPRUNE_FILES
BACULA_LOG_NOPRUNE_JOBS
BACULA_LOG_NOSTAT
BACULA_LOG_NOSUIT
BACULA_LOG_PRUNED_FILES
BACULA_LOG_PRUNED_JOBS
BACULA_LOG_READYAPPEND
BACULA_LOG_STARTJOB
BACULA_LOG_STARTRESTORE
BACULA_LOG_USEDEVICE
BACULA_LOG_VOLUME_PREVWRITTEN
BACULA_LOG_VSS
BACULA_LOG_WROTE_LABEL
BACULA_TIMESTAMP
BACULA_VERSION
BACULA_VOLUME
BASE10NUM
BASE16FLOAT
BASE16NUM
BIND9
BIND9_TIMESTAMP
BRO_CONN
BRO_DNS
BRO_FILES
BRO_HTTP
CATALINA_DATESTAMP
CATALINALOG
CISCO_ACTION
CISCO_DIRECTION
CISCOFW104001
CISCOFW104002
CISCOFW104003
CISCOFW104004
CISCOFW105003
CISCOFW105004
CISCOFW105005
CISCOFW105008
CISCOFW105009
CISCOFW106001
CISCOFW106006_106007_106010
CISCOFW106014
CISCOFW106015
CISCOFW106021
CISCOFW106023
CISCOFW106100
CISCOFW106100_2_3
CISCOFW110002
CISCOFW302010
CISCOFW302013_302014_302015_302016
CISCOFW302020_302021
CISCOFW304001
CISCOFW305011
CISCOFW313001_313004_313008
CISCOFW313005
CISCOFW321001
CISCOFW402117
CISCOFW402119
CISCOFW419001
CISCOFW419002
CISCOFW500004
CISCOFW602303_602304
CISCOFW710001_710002_710003_710005_710006
CISCOFW713172
CISCOFW733100
CISCO_INTERVAL
CISCOMAC
CISCO_REASON
CISCOTAG
CISCO_TAGGED_SYSLOG
CISCOTIMESTAMP
CISCO_XLATE_TYPE
CLOUDFRONT_ACCESS_LOG
COMBINEDAPACHELOG
COMMONAPACHELOG
COMMONMAC
CRON_ACTION
CRONLOG
DATA
DATE
DATE_EU
DATESTAMP
DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG
DATESTAMP_OTHER
DATESTAMP_RFC2822
DATESTAMP_RFC822
DATE_US
DAY
ELB_ACCESS_LOG
ELB_REQUEST_LINE
ELB_URI
ELB_URIPATHPARAM
EMAILADDRESS
EMAILLOCALPART
EXIM_DATE
EXIM_EXCLUDE_TERMS
EXIM_FLAGS
EXIM_HEADER_ID
EXIM_INTERFACE
EXIM_MSGID
EXIM_MSG_SIZE
EXIM_PID
EXIM_PROTOCOL
EXIM_QT
EXIM_REMOTE_HOST
EXIM_SUBJECT
GREEDYDATA
HAPROXYCAPTUREDREQUESTHEADERS
HAPROXYCAPTUREDRESPONSEHEADERS
HAPROXYDATE
HAPROXYHTTP
HAPROXYHTTPBASE
HAPROXYTCP
HAPROXYTIME
HOSTNAME
HOSTPORT
HOUR
HTTPD20_ERRORLOG
HTTPD24_ERRORLOG
HTTPDATE
HTTPD_COMBINEDLOG
HTTPD_COMMONLOG
HTTPDERROR_DATE
HTTPD_ERRORLOG
HTTPDUSER
INT
IP
IPORHOST
IPV4
IPV6
ISO8601_SECOND
ISO8601_TIMEZONE
JAVACLASS
JAVACLASS
JAVAFILE
JAVAFILE
JAVALOGMESSAGE
JAVAMETHOD
JAVASTACKTRACEPART
JAVATHREAD
LOGLEVEL
MAC
MAVEN_VERSION
MCOLLECTIVE
MCOLLECTIVEAUDIT
MCOLLECTIVEAUDIT
MINUTE
MONGO3_COMPONENT
MONGO3_LOG
MONGO3_SEVERITY
MONGO_LOG
MONGO_QUERY
MONGO_SLOWQUERY
MONGO_WORDDASH
MONTH
MONTHDAY
MONTHNUM
MONTHNUM2
NAGIOS_CURRENT_HOST_STATE
NAGIOS_CURRENT_SERVICE_STATE
NAGIOS_EC_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK
NAGIOS_EC_DISABLE_HOST_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_DISABLE_HOST_SVC_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_DISABLE_SVC_CHECK
NAGIOS_EC_DISABLE_SVC_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_ENABLE_HOST_CHECK
NAGIOS_EC_ENABLE_HOST_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_ENABLE_HOST_SVC_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_ENABLE_SVC_CHECK
NAGIOS_EC_ENABLE_SVC_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_DISABLE_HOST_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_DISABLE_HOST_SVC_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_DISABLE_SVC_CHECK
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_DISABLE_SVC_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_ENABLE_HOST_CHECK
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_ENABLE_HOST_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_ENABLE_HOST_SVC_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_ENABLE_SVC_CHECK
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_ENABLE_SVC_NOTIFICATIONS
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT
NAGIOS_EC_LINE_SCHEDULE_HOST_DOWNTIME
NAGIOS_EC_PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT
NAGIOS_EC_PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT
NAGIOS_EC_SCHEDULE_HOST_DOWNTIME
NAGIOS_EC_SCHEDULE_SERVICE_DOWNTIME
NAGIOS_HOST_ALERT
NAGIOS_HOST_DOWNTIME_ALERT
NAGIOS_HOST_EVENT_HANDLER
NAGIOS_HOST_FLAPPING_ALERT
NAGIOS_HOST_NOTIFICATION
NAGIOSLOGLINE
NAGIOS_PASSIVE_HOST_CHECK
NAGIOS_PASSIVE_SERVICE_CHECK
NAGIOS_SERVICE_ALERT
NAGIOS_SERVICE_DOWNTIME_ALERT
NAGIOS_SERVICE_EVENT_HANDLER
NAGIOS_SERVICE_FLAPPING_ALERT
NAGIOS_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION
NAGIOSTIME
NAGIOS_TIMEPERIOD_TRANSITION
NAGIOS_TYPE_CURRENT_HOST_STATE
NAGIOS_TYPE_CURRENT_SERVICE_STATE
NAGIOS_TYPE_EXTERNAL_COMMAND
NAGIOS_TYPE_HOST_ALERT
NAGIOS_TYPE_HOST_DOWNTIME_ALERT
NAGIOS_TYPE_HOST_EVENT_HANDLER
NAGIOS_TYPE_HOST_FLAPPING_ALERT
NAGIOS_TYPE_HOST_NOTIFICATION
NAGIOS_TYPE_PASSIVE_HOST_CHECK
NAGIOS_TYPE_PASSIVE_SERVICE_CHECK
NAGIOS_TYPE_SERVICE_ALERT
NAGIOS_TYPE_SERVICE_DOWNTIME_ALERT
NAGIOS_TYPE_SERVICE_EVENT_HANDLER
NAGIOS_TYPE_SERVICE_FLAPPING_ALERT
NAGIOS_TYPE_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION
NAGIOS_TYPE_TIMEPERIOD_TRANSITION
NAGIOS_WARNING
NETSCREENSESSIONLOG
NONNEGINT
NOTSPACE
NUMBER
PATH
POSINT
POSTGRESQL
PROG
QS
QUOTEDSTRING
RAILS3
RAILS3FOOT
RAILS3HEAD
RAILS3PROFILE
RCONTROLLER
REDISLOG
REDISMONLOG
REDISTIMESTAMP
RPROCESSING
RT_FLOW1
RT_FLOW2
RT_FLOW3
RT_FLOW_EVENT
RUBY_LOGGER
RUBY_LOGLEVEL
RUUID
S3_ACCESS_LOG
S3_REQUEST_LINE
SECOND
SFW2
SHOREWALL
SPACE
SQUID3
SYSLOG5424BASE
SYSLOG5424LINE
SYSLOG5424PRI
SYSLOG5424PRINTASCII
SYSLOG5424SD
SYSLOGBASE
SYSLOGBASE2
SYSLOGFACILITY
SYSLOGHOST
SYSLOGLINE
SYSLOGPAMSESSION
SYSLOGPROG
SYSLOGTIMESTAMP
TIME
TIMESTAMP_ISO8601
TOMCAT_DATESTAMP
TOMCATLOG
TTY
TZ
UNIXPATH
URI
URIHOST
URIPARAM
URIPATH
URIPATHPARAM
URIPROTO
URN
USER
USERNAME
UUID
WINDOWSMAC
WINPATH
WORD
YEAR
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Logstash as a package, they can be found at /opt/logstash/patterns/grok-patterns.

Comment: Please mind explaining your answer a little bit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can view using these commands:

```
# find / -name patterns

/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-patterns-core-2.0.5/patterns

/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-patterns-core-2.0.5/lib/logstash/patterns
```

Just browse to the directory

```
# cd  /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-patterns-core-2.0.5/patterns
```

And here you have a whole list of patterns

```
aws                   exim                  haproxy            
linux-syslog          mongodb               rails
bacula                firewalls             java                  mcollective           nagios                redis
bro                   grok-patterns         junos                 mcollective-patterns  postgresql            ruby
```